# How to get AD information for an AWS EC2 instance from AWS sdk for .NET

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, aws-sdk

When importing AWS ec2 instances from AWS using their SDK, there is a unique field called the Instance ID. This information is specific to Amazon. Some of these instances can be part of the domain too. Can I get the AD Object GUID during this AWS import?
Or is there another field that I can use to link the AWS instance imported from AWS with the instance imported from AD?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you cannot get the AD GUID using AWS SDK unless you store it as an instance tag. Because all instance attributes are specific to AWS. Without knowing how AD GUID is linked to AWS instance id, it is difficult to comment.

The simplest solution is to tag the instance (like `tag:AD_GUID=<GUID>`) when launching (or after launching) the instance. Then using AWS SDK, you can get the AD GUID of the instance form instance's attributes.